# Altium - Polygon pour into a cutout

Tags: altium, copper-pour, polygon

I'm using Altium Designer 22 to design a PCB. On the top layer I have a ground plane with a hole in the middle. I made the hole by using a polygon cutout. Now, I have to pour into this cutout region some polygons, but I'm not able to do this. Do you have any solution to address this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options:

1. As mentioned, shape the ground polygon so it avoids the area.
2. Delete the cutout and place the desired polygon; set pour order on the manager so it pours first.  GND will clear around it.
3. Do as #2, but reshape/place a new cutout so it clears the border between polygons.  (Now the exact shape of both polygons is less critical, and clearances can be set manually by its shape.)

2a: Do as #2, and set clearance rule between nets, or polygons, or whatever exactly you're after, to do the same as #3 but automatically.  This assumes the clearance is uniform, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a polygon cut-out then you can't.

One solution is to draw the polygon manually in a way that it has that hole:

[image]

I have exaggerated the top gap but sure the edges should kiss each other.